# Insert Xnumber of rows across multiple sheets using Inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

Almost have it working. Getting unusual results. Having a difficult time finding information to get me to the finish line. What's working...
InputBox is asking me how many rows to insert. I can Select the multiple sheets to add rows to. I can find and select the last row in the table.  When I try to copy the row (w/formulas), and paste the desired number of rows across the sheets, everything goes wrong. The 2nd and 3rd sheets work fine. The first sheet adds the rows *2 (Exp: Add 10...result is 20 rows).  Here's what I have so far...

```
Dim iRows As Integer
Dim sRows As String

sRows = InputBox("How many rows do you want to add? (Between 1 - 100)")
iRows = Int(Val(sRows))
Sheets(Array("ETC LABOR LOE", "ETC LABOR HOURS", "ETC LABOR COST")).Select
Range("A9").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

For i = 1 To iRows
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Next
```

This isn't all of it, but I'm hoping it is enough to get the point across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not replicate the results mentioned using your code, instead I got the correct number of rows inserted but only in the first sheet. Now it seems that there is not data below the line you want to be inserted as you are using the last row to determine it. If that is the case you could use copy instead of insert.

I’m presenting two methods:

1. To Insert or Copy *(both options are commented, please uncomment the one you want to use)* all required rows at once. This method primarily depends on the use of `Select`.
2. To Insert or Copy *(both options are commented, please uncomment the one you want to use)* all required rows by worksheet. I prefer this method as it does not use `Select`.

*First Method*

```
Sub Insert_LastRow_AtOnce()
Dim bRows As Byte



    Rem Ask input from user
    bRows = Application.InputBox("How many rows do you want to add? (Between 1 - 100)", Type:=2)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ETC LABOR LOE")

'NOTE: If you want to use Copy uncomment this block
        Rem Copy
'        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
'        .Range("A9").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(bRows).Select
'        Sheets(Array("ETC LABOR LOE", "ETC LABOR HOURS", "ETC LABOR COST")).Select
'        Range("A9").End(xlDown).EntireRow.Copy
'        ActiveSheet.Paste
'        Application.CutCopyMode = False

'NOTE: If you want to use Copy\Insert uncomment this block
        Rem Copy\Insert
'        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
'        .Range("A9").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(bRows).Select
'        Sheets(Array("ETC LABOR LOE", "ETC LABOR HOURS", "ETC LABOR COST")).Select
'        Range("A9").End(xlDown).EntireRow.Copy
'        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

    End Sub
```

*Second Method*

```
Sub Insert_LastRow_ByWsh()
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim bRows As Byte

    Rem Ask input from user
    bRows = Application.InputBox("How many rows do you want to add? (Between 1 - 100)", Type:=2)

    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("ETC LABOR LOE", "ETC LABOR HOURS", "ETC LABOR COST"))
        With wsh

'NOTE: If you want to use Copy uncomment this block
            Rem Copy
'            .Range("A9").End(xlDown).EntireRow.Copy
'            .Range("A9").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(bRows).PasteSpecial
'            Application.CutCopyMode = False

'NOTE: If you want to use Copy\Insert uncomment this block
            Rem Copy\Insert
'            .Range("A9").End(xlDown).EntireRow.Copy
'            .Range("A9").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(bRows).Insert Shift:=xlDown
'            Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With: Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent!  All of these options work great.  I ended up going with Method 1 - Option 2 (Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown). I am new to stackoverflow and I want to make sure that I follow etiquette.  I'm not sure what you mean by "uncomment this block".  Please let me know and I'll follow up.

Comment: @Jim.A a very important part of the interaction in the site is to accept the answer that solves your problem. That's the correct way to tell other users about it, and also to help us to keep the site updated. So please do your part and accept the answer that solved your problem. Thanks...